# Is Ax = b solvable in the integers, if it is solvable modulo m for all natural numbers m?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Suppose $A$ is a $m \times n$ - matrix with integer entries and $b$ a column vector with integer entries. Is it true, that $Ax = b$ has an integral solution, if $Ax = b$ (mod $m$)
 is solvable for all natural numbers $m$? How can it be proven?

The other direction of the claim is clear : If $Ax = b$ has an integral solution,
 then $Ax = b$ (mod $m$) is solvable for all $m$ (simply take the coefficients of $x$
 modulo $m$). For one equation, the claim is also clear : $x_1a_1 + ... + x_na_n = b$
 with integers $a_1,...a_n,b$ has an integral solution if and only if 
 $gcd(a_1,...,a_n)|b$. So, if the equation is not solvable, there is no solution
 modulo $m:=gcd(a_1,...,a_n)$ (If $m = 1$, the equation always has a solution).

But I have no idea how to generalize this for equation systems.

The problem is only interesting, if $Ax = b$ has infinitely many solutions
 in the rationals, which can be quickly checked. If the kernel of $A$ has
 dimension 1, the problem is also quite simple.

I tried the following : Assume , the general solution of $Ax = b$ is

$\frac{x}{m} + c_1k_1 + ... +c_nk_n$ , where $x,k_1,...,k_n$ are integral vectors
 and $m > 1$

Then, if we can find $d_1,...d_n$ with $x+ d_1k_1 +...+ d_nk_n = 0\ (mod\ m)$
 we can build an integral solution with $c_i:=\frac{d_i}{m}$ , i=1,...,n.
 Is this sufficient condition also necessary ? If yes, then there would at least
 be a brute-force-method working modulo m.

Finally, is checking the integer-solvability of $Ax = b$ NP-hard ?

Comment: Closely related to my question : When is Ax = b solveable in the integers ?

Comment: there was an article in Mathematics magazine http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2690528?uid=3739824&uid=2&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=21103901309051

Comment: http://www.math.udel.edu/~lazebnik/papers/dior1.pdf

Comment: @bobbym Great link! Thank you very much!

Comment: Search on Hermite/Smith normal form to get started.